# SuSE Linux 12.4 - cannot re-register in Azure - object has no attribute 'generateRegionSrvArgs'

Tags: linux, azure, python, sles

My Azure VM running Linux SLES 12.4 got de-reigstered in Azure.
When trying to register back, i get:

**/etc/zypp/repos.d # /usr/sbin/registercloudguest --force-new**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/registercloudguest", line 279, in <module>
    region_smt_data = utils.fetch_smt_data(cfg, proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cloudregister/registerutils.py", line 238, in fetch_smt_data
    api = add_region_server_args_to_URL(api, cfg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cloudregister/registerutils.py", line 87, in add_region_server_args_to_URL
    regionSrvArgs = mod.generateRegionSrvArgs()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'generateRegionSrvArgs'
```

Cleaned repos and other Azure connection data per this KB: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019085
but not getting any better

Checked Internets but haven found any clue of similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/suse-public-cloud-connectivity-registration-issues) which addresses a situation in which an Azure virtual machine (VM) is set up by using a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) image, but the VM can't connect to the SUSE Subscription Management Tool (SMT) repository.

The article describes some basic troubleshooting steps, and it outlines actions to take for specific scenarios (such as failures in Zypper, which is the SUSE command-line tool for managing packages).

This information was assembled by Linux specialists at Microsoft, and it's based on support experience and documentation from SUSE.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).